# Pandas Dataframe comparison with range/stdev

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, range

I have to dataframes A and B. Both have a 'datetime' column and another common column X. B is bigger as it has X at every minute while A only has X at intermittent times during a day. For each 'datetime' in A, I want to calculate the range (or stdev) of X during previous 30 minutes using B. So something like:

`For i,time in enumerate(A['time']): 
   temp=B[(B['time'] > time -timedelta(days=0, minutes=30)) and (B['time'] <=time]
   range[i]=temp.max-temp.min`

Here temp is intended to snapshot all the data within 30 mins prior to A's timestamp in B. Is there a simple way, maybe one that doesn't require a loop, to do this? Note that sizes of A and B are different.

Sample A: (only few outputs available along with inputs)

`Date                         input  output 
2015-01-02 20:48:00-00:00     1120    343 
2015-01-02 21:25:00-00:00     1345    365`

Sample B: ( all the inputs available but no outputs)

`Date                         input 
2014-11-02 00:32:00-00:00     1542
2014-11-02 00:33:00-00:00     1285`

Sample Output:

`Date                         input  output  Range_input_previous 30 min 
2015-01-02 20:48:00-00:00     1120    343      ??(use table B)
2015-01-02 21:25:00-00:00     1345    365      ??(use table B)`

Comment: can you provide sample of both the data frames?

Comment: Added. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Can you add desired output?

Comment: Added. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you. I think the best is use such values in sample which return some numbers.

Comment: There is main problem your conditions return only `False`, so I cannot test it. So you need change datetime to values, where return `True`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me but uses a loop:

`rangex=np.zeros(A.shape[0])

 for i,Date in enumerate(A['Date']):
     temp=B[(B['Date'] > Date-datetime.timedelta(days=0, minutes=30)) & (B['Date'] <=Date)]
     rangex[i]=temp['input'].max()-temp['input'].min()

 A['range']=pd.Series(rangex, index=A.index)`